# Changes in java code not refelecting when i run the application

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I was recently running java application and the computer stopped working(hung) and i had to cold boot it. I restarted the computer and all is okay, but when i make changes in the code, they don't reflect on my application after running it. The changes are only reflected when i  build (or clean and build). This consumes a lot of time especially when i want to test anything. Anyone who has an idea of what went wrong?

Comment: Is there a setting in netbeans to auto-build that might have gotten turned off?

Comment: Check the system clock is set to correct or not sometimes this causes the problem

Comment: @ POP The system time is correct

Comment: Right click on project to get Project properties. In project properties, go to build compiling. Check if compile on save checkbox is selected. If not select it. Also, go to Run, and check/select the Deploy on save checkbox if it is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i get you question but i will try to help.

All compilers for advanced languages must compile and save your raw code as binary somewhere. Once your code is compiled, you acquire a complete package of binary. When you change your code it cant be injected to your binary. That is reverse engineering and its not a way to develop a program from scratch. If your build progress is getting longer and longer all you can do is dividing your code into pieces, compiling those pieces and using those programs (pieces) in your mainframe. Like a mash up.